# How to pass information from a playbook to another?

Tags: python, linux, ansible, redhat

I have a python application that helps me build a job which contains multiple playbooks. Something like below and upon job execution, ansible will play the playbooks in remote host one by one:

Job:

1. playbook_01

   - task1
2. playbook_02

   - task1
3. playbook_03

   - task1
4. playbook_04

   - task1

Each of these playbooks require remote host information such as OS release major version (e.g. 7 for RHEL7.9).

How can I gather the required host information once and use it for all playbooks instead of gathering every time I run each play.

I know that I can set `gather_facts: true` in each playbook before execution of tasks, but this is a bit slow as I have to gather facts for a total of 4 times when I run all 4 playbooks in the example above.

I have tried using the `register` module following this [guide](https://www.unixarena.com/2019/05/passing-variable-from-one-playbook-to-another-playbook-ansible.html/) but that didn't work as I cannot use `import_playbook` or `include`.

Say all my playbooks look something like below and run command with some host information, how can I reuse the facts gathered in the 1st playbook?

```
---
- hosts: "{{ host }}"
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:
    - name: "Run command in remote server"
      shell: {{some_ansible_fact_variable}}...
```

OR

How can I use a registered variable in the 1st playbook and reuse for subsequent playbooks?

```
# playbook_01
---
- hosts: "{{ host }}"
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: "Getting facter os.release.major"
      shell: facter os.release.major
      register: OSMajorVersion

    - name: "Run command in remote server"
      shell: {{OSMajorVersion.stdout}}...
```

```
# playbook_02
---
- hosts: "{{ host }}"
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: "Run command in remote server"
      shell: {{OSMajorVersion.stdout}}...
```

#Edit
Each playbook is added to an AnsibleTask class and executed and run as python process

```py
class AnsibleTask(object):
      def run(self):
        split_cmd = shlex.split(self.cmd)

        # Set log file
        self.process_env['ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH'] = '{}/{}.log'.format(
                config['ansible']['ansible_logs_dir'],
                self.props['hostname'])

        logger.info("running command: %s" % self.cmd)

        p = subprocess.Popen(
                split_cmd,
                cwd=self.playbooks_path,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                env=self.process_env)
        output, error = p.communicate()
        p.wait()

    def execute(self):
        self.process_env['ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK'] = 'json'
        (ret, out, err) = self.run()
        host = self.props['host']

        try:
            out_dict = json.loads(out)
        except ValueError as e:
            logger.error('error parsing json: %s' % str(e))
            raise AnsibleTaskError(AnsibleTaskError.E_PARSE_JSON)

        if ret > 0:
            ...
        else:
            return out_dict
```

Comment: Could you please add the commands using which you trigger each playbook.

Comment: @ShubhamVaishnav have added some python code, hope it helps. I'm using python process to run playbook in remote host